# Could not obtain a WAC Access Token while trying to access excel file on SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I read some of the questions that were asked pertaining to the same issue I'm having, but none of the answers helped.

I am trying to read or get the cell data values of an excel file (.xlsx) stored in a SharePoint site. I've already granted the following permissions, File.Read.All and Site.Read.All.

When I try to run the query below on MS Graph Explorer, I get *'Access Denied'*. I have the site-id and list-id populated in my query but not shown here.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/3/driveItem/workbook/worksheets/usedRange
```

**Response Preview**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Could not obtain a WAC access token.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-03T17:47:01",
            "request-id": "ccb9aa2e-ef69-4834-802c-f71d43ee1b78",
            "client-request-id": "c478..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its telling that you havent provided the necessary permissions to access the resource, hence its throwing the error. Copy the token and validate the same https://jwt.ms to see if it contains the necessary permissions to access the given resource or not.

Comment: @Dev Thanks for your response. The token does contain the necessary permission. Still stuck with the access denied response.

Comment: Ok outside of your code, try to repro the issue with Microsoft Graph Explorer and see if you can still repro the issue. If yes, then see if you can share the detailed response (with requestid, timestamp)

Comment: @Dev The issue I am having is with Microsoft Graph Explorer. The above Response Preview is what I got back from MS Graph Explorer. I was wanting to test the query on MS Graph Explorer before I ran the query inside my code. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear in my description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This had me scratching my head but I am finally able to access and operate on my excel file over SharePoint. I was accessing the excel file incorrectly.

I used the query below to get all the sites, including root level and sub sites:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

as using the one below didn't list the site I needed:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root
```

Because my excel file is within a folder on that site, I need to provide the *list-item-id* as the folder is an item of the site. Then, I am able to access the folder as a *drive* and use *root* to provide the path to the excel file from the folder's root directory. Finally, do whatever operation needed to the workbook.

```
.../v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-item-id}/drive/root:/{path-to-file}:/workbook/worksheets/{sheet-name or sheet-id}/usedRange
```

References:

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0#sharepoint-api-root-resources)

[Get a DriveItem Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

[Working with Excel in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I had issues trying to find "{site-id}" and I decided to give a shot using the property under "sharepointIds" in the /me/drive/sharedWithMe call. It worked. Thanks @SVang

Comment: To find site-id and other ids, I hit the F12 developer tools on my browser open to the OneDrive/Sharepoint folder of interest, hovered on the filename of interest, and then on the hover dialog, clicked "details" and looked at the GET.  From the F12 screen's GET location, I lopped out "_api/v2.1" and added "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites". Also realized about the need for a table (a Table as in "Insert-Table" menu in Excel) being ~declared that contains the rows and columns of interest on the worksheet of interest.  As far as I could tell, no table, no access for adding a row to a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks to @sirhcsivad's comment I managed to connect to my excel fil through Microsoft Graph without a site ID. After following the above instructions I did a PATCH request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive_id}}/items/{{item_id}}/workbook/worksheets/{{sheet_name}}/range(address='B{{start}}:B{{end}}')'`. Remember to check Excel in Microsoft Graph API to send a json body with values, formulas and numberFormat.